# In Drools, can a selection clause (using keyword `from`) be written over an Iterable or Iterator?

Tags: java, drools, mvel

Given a Java interface like this:

```
class Hobby {
    public String getName() {...}
}

class Person {
    public Iterable<Hobby> getHobbies() {...}
}
```

How can I, in a LHS expression, select Hobby objects with a specific name. For example, something like this:

```
when
    $person: Person()
    $hobby: Hobby(name == "Knitting") from $person.hobbies
```

Is this supposed to work? It doesn't produce any results when we tried it.

Is there an alternative, given the Java code that returns an `Iterable`, rather than a `Collection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the mismatch person/$person, the rule compiles and fires if there is a person with "Knitting" in the hobbies collection. (Version 5.5, but I have no doubt that other versions work just as well.)

```
rule "who knits"
when
  $person: Person( $name: name )
  Hobby(name == "Knitting") from $person.hobbies
then
  System.out.println( "Knitting: " + $name );
end

public class Person {
  private String name;
  private List<Hobby> hobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }  
  public Iterable<Hobby> getHobbies(){
     return hobbies;
  }
}
```

Also, I don't see any *Java interfaces* in the snippets you've posted, just two classes.

If you have a problem, make sure to provide full code to reproduce the example.

Comment: I fixed the typo (missing `$`) in the question. Note that the question is talking about "interface" in the informal sense (the public interface of some Java classes), not as a formal Java `interface`. I was writing the question without a Drools environment at hand so I apologize for the informalness of it.

Comment: I'll give it a try again in my BRMS environment and see if your specific example is working as intended.

Comment: I mentioned "interface" just to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Waiting for the code reproducing the problem. - Make sure to add Drools version.

Comment: The answer does indeed work, when the `Iterable` returned from the Java object is a standard Collection. For some reason, Drools does not like if Google Guava's `Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(Iterable<T>)` is used.